# How to implement an object's event loop?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, background-process

I have a class that handles some hardware. I want this class to check some state of the hardware every N milleseconds, and fire an event if a certain case is true.

I would like the interface on the outside to be such:

```
var rack = new Rack();
rack.ButtonPushed += OnButtonPushed;
rack.Initialise();
```

I want to avoid using "real" threads, but I don't seem to get the `Task` correctly (for testing, I just fire the event every second):

```
class Rack {
  public event EventHandler ButtonPushed;
  public void Initialise()
  {
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task.Delay(1000);
            ButtonPushed?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work, the events get fired all at the same time.

Is `Task` the right thing to use here, or should I work with a Timer, or a thread?

Comment: Shouldn't you be e.g. `await`ing for that `Task.Delay()` to complete..? See the Example for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_

Comment: _"I want this class to check some state of the hardware every N milleseconds, and fire an event if a certain case is true"_  Maybe use [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0) then?

Comment: When you have added `async` to the Task, you should probably provide means to cancel this Task. A default CancellationToken may do (plus a public method added to the Rack class).

Comment: I second Guru. Task is not the tool of choice. Either a Timer or a Scheduling Framework is.

Comment: Even with not awaited use of `Task.Delay` I'm not able [to reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WOwH8D) the issue with event handler beeing null.

Comment: Microsoft's reactive framework is awesome for this: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Subscribe(n => /* Do something */);`

Comment: @Fabjan Not sure what exactly are you talking about. Can you explain a little bit more? Also are you sure you are not confusing `SynchronizationContext` in ASP with Thread Context and Framework ? Aslo switching to Framework still [does not reproduce the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hqz3Wx).

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, sorry I mean't `SynchronizationContext`

Comment: @Fabjan still not sure how it is related (though threading in theory can).

Comment: @GuruStron that was my mistake. I had two instances running; one of them didn't register an event handler.

Comment: @GuruStron I decided on the `Timer`. Simpler to implement and cleaner code (plus I couldn't get the `Task` version to run correctly)

Answer (score 3):

Task delay returns a task that finishes execution after given time and needs to be awaited. In order to await it we'd need to mark the delegate as `async` and add `await` before the call:

```
class Rack {
  public event EventHandler ButtonPushed;
  public void Initialise()
  {
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ButtonPushed?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

> Is Task the right thing to use here, or should I work with a Timer, or
> a thread?

Well, your approach is just as good as using Timer. Thread could be used as well but it's a bit too low-level approach.

As others mentioned it would be better with `CancellationToken`, this allows us to cancel the task later so it finishes execution:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Most likely it happens because of a different thread context. We attach handler in one thread but fire events in another thread

Comment: To answer that we need more details. Is it a console app or an app with GUI ? Which version of .NET Framework/Core did you use ?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason for the event handler to remain `null` if you follow the answer

Comment: Sorry I meant `SynchronizationContext` not `ThreadContext`

Comment: This works, but when I update a `TextBox.Text` property in the event handler, it seems to hang. I guess this is some kind of threading issue? It is a WinForms application BTW,  .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @BartFriederichs strange that it is hanging AFAIK it should just throw. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread).

Comment: @GuruStron note the application doesn't hang, but when stepping through, it just switches back to the app and nothing is updated, so it looks like the Task hangs/blocks. Any subsequent calls aren't fired either.

Comment: Pass a `Progress<T>` delegate to the Task. Or `BeginInvoke()` (not `Invoke()`) in the event handler. Your event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread: you need to marshal to the UI Thread to modify properties of UI elements.